# poisson process arrivals (insurance company: accidents and time until a claim is reported)

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Policy holders of an insurance company have accidents at times of a
>   Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. The distribution of the time $R$ until a claim is reported is random with $P(R ≤ r) = G(r)$ and $ER = ν$. (a) Find the
>   distribution of the number of unreported claims. (b) Suppose each claim has
>   mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$. 
>   Find the mean and variance of the total size $S$ of the
>   unreported claims.

*Attempt.* $(a)$ Thinning would be my first thought, but I would need an 
rv from the Bernoulli distribution, being $+1$ if the claim is reported (with probability $p=?$) and $0$ if the claim is unreported 
(with probability $1-p$). I am having difficulty finding $p$.

$(b)$ Here we use the definitions, since 
$\displaystyle E(S^m)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^mP(S=k)$  ($m=1,2$) and $V(S)=E(S^2)-E(S)^2.$

Thank you in advance.